# HELP with inverse kinematics

Tags: robotic-arm

i need help with solving the inverse kinematics for the following robotic arm https://www.sunrobotics.in/shop/9170-sunrobotics-aluminium-alloy-based-4dof-robotic-arm-diy-kit-arduino-based-open-source-metal-gripper-pot-controlled-unassembled-23788?search=4+dof#attr=
its a 4 dof arm with a elbow offset of 1.5cm link are L1 = 9.5 L2 = 11 L3 = 7
i refered the vidyasagar book on robotic modelling where this is defined i need help with solving the IK

Comment: You need to provide the DH parameters for a robot arm before asking for IK help.